# How would an ngBindCompile directive be written?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

How would a directive that is similar to ngBindTemplate be written, where instead of taking a string which is the template, it takes a variable that contains the template? i.e.:

Existing:

```
ng-bind-template="{template}"
```

To write:

```
 ng-bind-compile="var"
```

where `var="{template}"`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how that could be done using `$compile` in the context of the directive's parent scope:

```
app.directive('ngBindCompile',function($compile){
    return {
        scope:{
            template: '=ngBindCompile'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var html = '<div>' + scope.template + '</div>';
            var compiled = $compile(html)(scope.$parent);
            element.replaceWith(compiled);
        }
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/4Uy5K/)